# Simulate SHL and SHR ASM instructions in Python

Tags: python, assembly, x86-64

In x86_64 ASM, the following instructions perform bitwise shift left and right respectively.

```
SHL rax, cl
SHR rax, cl
```

I would like to simulate these instructions in Python.

For a value such as: 0x613025F862, I can do the following:

```
result = 0x613025F862 << 0x10
```

However, for larger values, I get a different result:

```
0x60018DDDBD500063 << 0x10
```

It gives me the result as: 0x60018dddbd5000630000. However, in ASM, the result would be: 0x8dddbd5000630000

I can get the above result in Python by doing the following:

```
(0x60018DDDBD500063 << 0x10) & 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Now, how can I write an efficient generic function which gives the correct result?

I have written a function as shown below for this purpose:

```
def shift_left(input):
    result = input << 0x10
    if result > 0xffffffffffffffff:
        result = result & 0xffffffffffffffff
    else:
        result = result

    return result
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to make the masking conditional. It works just fine for smaller values too.

Comment: I think it is. You just `AND` result with the mask of set bits and that's how you cut. Just removen your `if` and do `AND` everytime.
Or you might try integers from numpy, which are (int32, int64). But I think it will lead to negative numbers.

Comment: With Python alone there isn't a much better solution. Numpy has datatypes (signed and unsigned) and functions for efficient processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variable-count shifts, don't forget to mask the shift-count as well.  `shl` / `shr` only look at the low bits of `cl`.  Same for `bts reg,reg` or `reg,imm`, and for BMI2 `shlx r64, r64/m64, r64`.

Either `cl & 0x3f` for 64-bit shifts, or `cl & 0x1f` for 32, 16, or 8-bit shifts.  (So 16 and 8-bit shifts can zero an 8 or 16-bit register by shifting out all the bits).  See the Operation section of the manual for pseudocode: http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SAL:SAR:SHL:SHR.html

---

**You don't need to make the masking conditional**

```
result = (input << 0x10) & 0xffffffffffffffff

  or 
result = (input << (cl & 0x3f)) & 0xffffffffffffffff
```

Python2 has a fixed-width integer type which would implicitly discard high bits for you, but Python3 doesn't.

For right shift, you probably don't need to mask, assuming Python's integer types don't turn into floating-point or fixed-point when you right shift.

---

I'm also not sure how Python handles signed integers: `shr` shifts in zeros, while `sar` shifts in copies of the sign bit.  **In x86 asm, `-1` and `0xffffffffffffffff` are literally the same thing (all bits set)**, so in Python you might find you need to normalize the input for `shr` to be unsigned in the `0 .. 0xffffffffffffffff` range, or for `sar` normalize the input to be signed in the `-2^63 .. +2^63-1` range.

A left shift can "overflow" and set the high bit of the result.  Any instructions that look at the value with a signed interpretation will see it as negative.  (e.g. `sar`, widening one-operand `imul ecx`, or `test`/`cmp`/ other instructions that set `SF` and `OF`.)

And of course in a 32, 16, or 8-bit register, the top bit of that register is the sign bit.